# Resizing a marker icon in OpenLayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I have an icon that 4px by 4px and I use it as a marker. However I want to display it larger than 4x4, lets say 40px x 40px for example. Here is my code

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    size: [40, 40],
                    offset: [-20, -20],
                    //anchor: [0.5, 1],                    
                    src: "/images/historymarker.png",
                    opacity: 1,
                    id: num + "_" + x
                }))
            });            
            marker.setStyle(iconStyle);
```

However the icons comes out as it original size, Is there a way to resize it? I thought that size would have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale`:

```
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                    scale: 10,
                    offset: [-20, -20],
                    //anchor: [0.5, 1],                    
                    src: "/images/historymarker.png",
                    opacity: 1,
                    id: num + "_" + x
                }))
            });            
            marker.setStyle(iconStyle);
```

[Documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon-Icon.html)

[Example with a scale of 0.5](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.5.0_icon_scaled.html)

Comment: Thanks for assistance. Didn't need the offset line in the end either, just the scale. Every days a school day